# How long has the f-word been in use as an abusive term?

Tags: etymology, slang

When was the f-word 'invented'? Who invented it? Has it always had the derogatory meaning that it does today. Is it a recent invention?

Comment: And I think avoiding to spell out the word is bad because we want to be searchable, right?  But if "fuck" is not written "fuck", someone looking for this info won't find this question.

Comment: Could this word be in any way related to "pluck"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wikipedia has [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuck):

> It is unclear whether the word has always been considered vulgar, and if not, when it first came to be used to describe (often in an extremely angry, hostile or belligerent manner) unpleasant circumstances or people in an intentionally offensive way [...]

And:

> The *Oxford English Dictionary* states that the ultimate etymology is uncertain, but that the word is "probably cognate" with a number of native Germanic words with meanings involving striking, rubbing, and having sex.

Etymonline offers [further insight](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=fuck&searchmode=none):

> until recently a difficult word to trace, in part because it was taboo to the editors of the original Oxford English Dictionary when the "F" volume was compiled, 1893-97. Written form only attested from early 16c. Oxford English Dictionary 2nd edition cites 1503, in the form *fukkit*; earliest appearance of current spelling is 1535 -- "Bischops ... may fuck thair fill and be vnmaryit" [Sir David Lyndesay, "*Ane Satyre of the Thrie Estaits*"], but presumably it is a much more ancient word than that, simply one that wasn't written in the kind of texts that have survived from Old English and Middle English.
>
> [...]
>
> Verbal phrase *fuck up* "to ruin, spoil, destroy" first attested c.1916. [...] *Fuck off* attested from 1929; as a command to depart, by 1944. *Flying fuck* originally meant "have sex on horseback" and is first attested c.1800 in broadside ballad "*New Feats of Horsemanship*." For the unkillable urban legend that this word is an acronym of some sort (a fiction traceable on the Internet to 1995 but probably predating that) see [here](http://www.etymonline.com/baloney.php), and also [here](http://www.snopes.com/language/acronyms/fuck.asp). [...] Agent noun *fucker* attested from 1590s in literal sense; by 1893 as a term of abuse (or admiration).

Comment: Good Lord. This word is that old ! I thought it was some invention from the early 1900s or something.

Comment: I'm intrigued... Was a *flying fuck* a common thing back in the days, or was that another figure of speech? :)

Comment: @Rao - as a guide, the shorter and more common the word = the older it is. Your language needs a word for fuck long before it needs a word for disambiguation.

Answer (score 2):

As per the origin of the word, the NOAD reports that:

> ORIGIN early 16th cent.: of Germanic origin (compare Swedish dialect *focka* and Dutch dialect *fokkelen*); possibly from an Indo-European root meaning *strike*, shared by Latin *pugnus* (*fist*).

Comment: Also compare German vulgar *ficken* which has the same meaning

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the Swedish *focka*? I can't seem to recognize it at all... We do say *fucka upp* but that's clearly a very recent vikingization of the English vulgarism.

Answer (score 0):

I found interesting information on The Origin of the [F-Word](http://urbanlegends.about.com/library/bl-f-word.htm)

> Netlore Archive: In which we are told
>   with a straight face that the word
>   'fuck' originated as the acronym of
>   'Fornication Under Consent of the
>   King,' 'Fornication Under Command of
>   the King,' 'For Unlawful Carnal
>   Knowledge,' or some variation thereof.
>
> *Description:* Folk etymology
>   *Circulating since:* The 1960s
>   *Status:* False

I am guessing in 1960, its pejorative meaning got some traction

Comment: What the hell...