# What's the origin of the swear words like the 'F' word?

Tags: vocabulary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long has the f-word been in use as an abusive term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/how-long-has-the-f-word-been-in-use-as-an-abusive-term)

Sometimes I wonder what is the origin of some of the swear words such as the 'F**K' word which English speakers passionately use.  I know this query may sound distasteful, but I would appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: If anyone found this question distasteful, they shouldn't be here at all, IMNSHO.  Do such people (I have no doubt they *do* exist) edit their dictionaries to remove the "Seven Words You Can Never Say on Television"?

Comment: Of course, "they" wouldn't call it a dick-tionary ;-) (SCNR)

Comment: If your question is specifically about one word, then it's been covered in the other question. If it's about the origin of "swear words" in general, then it's not a real question, as they don't have a common origin. Each originated in different ways, just like any other English word.

Answer (score 0):

"Fuck" appears to be of unknown origin. It is my understanding that many English swear words are typically the English (of course) and the "polite forms" are typically of French origin.

Comment: It's of reasonably well-known origin. Related words are shared in other Germanic languages, and the origin has been traced back to Proto-Germanic.

Comment: Accepted. I recalled that the OED says "unknown."