# How did “fʌck” become taboo?

Tags: etymology, word-usage, offensive-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long has the f-word been in use as an abusive term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/how-long-has-the-f-word-been-in-use-as-an-abusive-term)
>   [What makes a word offensive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/what-makes-a-word-offensive)

I recognize that this is similar to [Etymology of the term "curse words" and "swear words"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53259/etymology-of-the-term-curse-words-and-swear-words) and [What makes a word offensive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/what-makes-a-word-offensive), but it’s not exactly the same: the former question is asking about the origin of the **term** *curse words*, not the origin of the curse words themselves, while the latter question is asking about what fundamentally makes a word taboo in society. I’m only interested in the history of a certain word in reference to its **meaning**, not its **usage**.

---

With that out of the way, my question is, how did the word *fuck* come to be? I looked up its etymology and found this:

> **ORIGIN** early 16th cent.: of Germanic origin (compare Swedish dialect *focka* and Dutch dialect *fokkelen*); possibly from an Indo-European root meaning ‘strike,’ shared by Latin *pugnus* ‘fist.’

But I don’t understand how a word being *strike* came to mean *have sexual intercourse with (someone)*.

Comment: I know it for the German equivalent, but I'm not sure how far that is substantive to the English word. But you should also have a look at the word [fidget](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fidget&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: I think the etymology at [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fuck&allowed_in_frame=0) is as comprehensive as you'll get.

Comment: @qegal Compare modern slang terms like “I’d hit it” or the fact that vigorous sex can be described as _pounding_, _banging_, etc. All words that literally have to do with some kind of striking being used to describe sex. Not at all an uncommon development.

Comment: @tchrist What's the rationale for the "search engine pessimization"  here? I thought the entire point of keeping duplicates around was to act as alternate search gateways to the canonical answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because of the chance that we’ll get blocked if our titles have Carlin-words in them.  So we obfuscate such words in the titles only.

Comment: @tchrist Ah thanks. If that's the consensus opinion might be worth adding something to that effect [to this meta question then](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/87/using-asterisks-as-in-fuck-or-fck/91#91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to various German online dictionaries, ficken – the German word for it – means both to poke and to rub or move back and forth...

Surely the word became taboo at the when Christianity "outlawed" it. Not meaning to bad mouth Christianity here, but many forms of sexual intercourse were indeed punishable by death in the dark ages.

Comment: But does the english version come from the "ficken"?

Comment: @qegal No, both words have the same root. On a German wiki page I just even read that the vulgar meaning first was quoted in English and 100 years later first time in German.

Comment: You're right I think: "The Oxford English Dictionary states that the ultimate etymology [of "fuck"] is uncertain, but that the word is "probably cognate" with a number of native Germanic words with meanings involving striking, **rubbing**, and having sex.
"

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fuck is a better explanation than I can give...

Comment: Regarding the "dark ages," it is not in general true that homosexuality/sodomy was punishable by death in the middle ages, although that certainly became more and more the case as the middle ages transitioned to the early modern era. Most of the brutality that we think of as "medieval" -- torture, burning, witch-hunts, sexual repression -- is *much* more representative of the modern era than the middle ages.

Comment: @Nick, what I heard you say: "Back in the 'dark ages' things were going well for the equal rights movement -- anyone could be lynched.. not just people in minorities"

Comment: @Born2Smile Ha ha ha. I'm no scholar of the middle ages, so I may well be wrong, but I gather that they really weren't as bad as people make them out to be. Carolingian civilization I gather was especially notable as a period of relative peace, prosperity, and cultural renaissance when it would have seemed impossible a century prior.